# Call fake not happening in unit testing of service method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

```
  function logOutUser() {
            var url = "User/Logout";
            httpWrapperService.post(url, {}, {}).then(function (success) {

            },
            function error(error) {

            });
            localStorageService.clearLocalStorage();
            httpWrapperService.setAuthenticationToken(null);
        }
```

Here is the code of testing

```
'use strict';

describe('Testing registration-service\n\n', function () {

var httpBackend = null;

var baseURL = null;
var services = {
    registration: null,
    settings: null,
    httpservice:null
};

// Initialization before tests
 beforeEach(function () {
        module("app");

        // Inject needed services
        inject(function ($httpBackend, _registrationService_, _settingsService_, _httpWrapperService_) {
            services.registration = _registrationService_;
            services.settings = _settingsService_;
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
            httpservice=_httpWrapperService_;
            //modal=$modal
            // Get baseurl
            baseURL = services.settings.getServicesURL();

            // Default answer
            httpBackend.whenGET("languages/en.json").respond("OK");
        });
    });

  describe('Checking logOutUser() function for different test cases!!!\n', function () {

    jasmine.createSpy('setAuthenticationToken').and.CallFake(function() {
      //a fake implementation
    });

    console.log("setAuthenticationToken===", setAuthenticationToken);

        it("1. When user is logged in \n", function (done) {
           localStorage.SA_User='{"tokenId":"TICKET_1","rememberMe":true}';
           var url = baseURL + "User/Logout";
           httpBackend.whenPOST(url, {}).respond({});
           expect(localStorage.SA_User).toEqual(undefined);
           ///expect(1).toEqual(1);
           done();
        });

    });

});
```

I have a function defined in registration service (logoutuser). I want to unit test this function . I dont want to call httpWrapperService.setAuthentication function. 
how can I do this , I tried using jasmine and spy using callfake but not able to do it in karma .

Any help is appreciated !!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `spyOn(services.httpservice, 'setAuthenticationToken').and.callFake(function(){})` instead of the `jasmine.createSpy`. This should add the spy to the service.

Comment: I am getting this error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAuthenticationToken' of null

Comment: when you inject the service, you are not setting it to `services.httpservice`. I assumed this is what you wanted to do. like you do with registration and settings

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you , can you please be more clear , what should I do ??

Comment: this line: `httpservice=_httpWrapperService_;` should be `services.httpservice=_httpWrapperService_;`

Comment: Are you getting the error in the test file or the application file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103007/discussion-between-shreya-and-gustav).